# Hardware simulator for MTK Phone based on mt6235

Tags: emulation

I'm trying to port uClinux to my Chinese phone which is an MTK phone based on mt6235 (ARM processor).

Does anyone know where I can get a hardware simulator for this kind of phone?

Answer (score 3):

mt6235 contain MMU. Therefore there is no need to go for uCLinux. Full-featured Linux kernel will run. See http://git.osmocom.org/gitweb?p=linux-mt623x.git

Answer (score 0):

just forwarding some more info from Osmocom regarding linux on mt6235:

- http://bb.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/SciphoneDreamG2
- http://lists.osmocom.org/pipermail/baseband-devel/2011-February/001344.html